# How do I call a permanent command prompt?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

In Windows, I made a small script to compile and then run a Java application:

```
javac helloWorld.java
java helloWorld
```

helloWorld prints "Hello, world!" and then the command prompt closes immediately. What I want to happen is for the program to execute then have a new line on the command prompt ready to go.

EDIT: 1 more stipulation. It needs to be just one batch file, not a batch file calling another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append the line:

```
cmd
```

...at the end of your batch file.

Comment: pause is the correct command for this. Hacking the interpreter is not the way to do it.

Comment: cmd is actually what I asked for, now I realize though, pause is what I need, so thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

you need to start an instance of cmd.exe and just let it run.

Answer (score 1):

You could start the script like this:

```
cmd /K script.cmd
```

This will keep the cmd shell open.

You can accomplish this by creating a desktop shortcut with the given line.